# How to get First Letter of First & Last name: Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Suppose, My Name is "Aerofoil Todo Kite" I want AK

I got a code from `Stackoverflow`. I hope it will work. But my question is, I am printing data from `Array of Objects` with `v-for` loop.

How do I pass the Name to compute that?

I think, Computed Property don't accept Parameter.

Then what will be the process??

Method can do. But It is calling for many times!!!

data:

```
tableData: [
  { customer: 'EE Fashion'}, 
  { customer: 'Tom Hangs Ron'}
}]

methods: {
 nameOfCompany(fullName) {
     console.log(fullName);
     return "HL";
 }
}
```

Code of Mine:

```
<template slot-scope="scope">
    <p style="margin-top: 5px;"><b>{{ nameOfCompany(scope.row.customer) }}</b></p>
 </template>
```

Here is the problem:

```
{{ nameOfCompany(scope.row.customer) }}
```

This function is calling for many times!!!!

**What will be the approach to do that?**

Comment: Forget about the name. Just think the name is Aerofoil Kite and give me the result AK. I mentioned I know how to achieve the last and first name from a big string. Just want to know the methodology to achieve it in Vue.js

Comment: you can use either `filters` or `computed` as demonstarted in below answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may write a `Customer` component so you only compute the company's name once:

It takes a name, and in data, computes the associated companyName.

```js
const mytable = {
  props: ['rows'],
  template: `
    <table>
      <tr v-for="row in rows">
        <slot :row="row"></slot> 
      </tr>
    </table>
  `
}

const mycustomer = {
  props: ['name'],
  data () {
    return {
      companyName: this.name.split(' ').map(x => x[0].toUpperCase()).join('')
    }
  },
  template: `
  <td>{{ name }} - <abbr>{{ companyName }}</abbr></td>
  `
}

let vm = new Vue({
  el:'#el',
  components: { mytable, mycustomer },
  template: `
    <mytable :rows="['grod zi', 'tu rok']">
      <template v-slot:default="{ row: user }">
        <mycustomer :name="user"/>
      </template>
    </mytable>
  `
});
```

```css
abbr {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="el"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use either **`filters`** or **`computed`**.

> ***Filters**: Vue.js allows you to define filters that can be used to apply common text formatting. Filters are usable in two places: mustache
> interpolations and v-bind expressions (the latter supported in
> 2.1.0+). Filters should be appended to the end of the JavaScript expression, denoted by the “pipe” symbol: [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)*

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: {
    tableData: [
      { customer: 'EE Fashion', company_name: "FOO BAR" }, 
      { customer: 'Tom Hangs Ron', company_name: "BAZ FOO BAR"},
      { customer: 'Jerry', company_name: "Lorem Ipsum Dorsum Zaren" }
    ],
  },
  
  filters: {
   short_hand (company_name) {
    // You can put your logic here...
    let words = company_name.split(" ")
    let short_hand = words[0][0] + words[words.length-1][0]
    return short_hand // <-- The return value as Per logic
   }
  },
  
  computed: {
   getTableData () {
    return this.tableData.map(data => {
      let words = data.company_name.split(" ")
      let short_hand = words[0][0] + words[words.length-1][0]
      return { short_hand, ...data }
    })
   }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  USING FILTER: <br>
  <div
    v-for="(data, i) in tableData"
    :key="'using-filter-'+i"
  >
    {{ data.company_name | short_hand }}
  </div>
  
  <hr> USING COMPUTED: <br>
  <div
    v-for="(data, i) in getTableData"
    :key="'using-computed-'+i"
  >
    {{ data.short_hand }}
  </div>
  
</div>
```